# Asus Zenfone 2 Stuck at White USB Logo

Tags: boot, asus-zenfone-2

My device has stuck displaying a white USB logo on boot. I have already tried a hard reboot (press power + volume up and select 'reboot') but the logo remains.

How can I get past this and boot the device properly?

Comment: A few things you can try without risking any data loss: Can you boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)? Can you boot into [recovery-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info)? From the latter, you can delete the cache ("Wipe Cache") and see if the device is able to boot then. The former lets you uninstall "problematic apps" which might be causing the issue (unlikely here if stuck directly at the boot logo, but still helpful to know if you can get there).